# Xcode 7.0, Ineligible devices while running on device. - Name's iPhone unavailable

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, swift

After updating Xcode to 7.0, and iOS 9 in my device, Xcode does not detects my device to test & deploy,

It shows `vinod's iPhone unavailable` while running the code.
but until Xcode 6.3 the app was running & deployed very well in the device.

Does anyone know how to resolve this?

Comment: Can you see device in Device's Window ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try follow any one solution to run build in your device.

1. Restart your iOS device (If device is recently updated) and your Xcode.
2. Make Sure that in build settings "iOS Deployment Target" is <= the version of your iDevice.
   [image]

Otherwise  goto - Product > Destination, select your device which would be showing as ineligible device.You will be able to select your device and run your build.

Comment: sorry I am updated my Xcode thats why I used this image

Comment: Oh great, it worked. Thank you. I changed the iOS Deployment target to 9.0

Comment: ya always remind this if you upgrade your os in your device and check the same deployment target available in your xcode , if yes just upgrade the deployment target else , upgrade the xcode