# OS Version issue with Xcode 6.4

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode6

I have created my project using Xcode 6.4 and swift 1.2.
Now I have updated my device with iOS 9.3. It was running completely fine with iOS 9.2. But after updating to 9.3 Xcode is showing my device as **ineligible devices**. Please help me to solve this.

Comment: see this once may be it helps you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32739233/xcode-7-0-ineligible-devices-while-running-on-device-names-iphone-unavailab

Comment: I have restarted my xcode and device both, but it doesn't work

Comment: actually your device version is higher than your xcode version , just upgrade your xcode version and try it will work bro

Comment: but the code is giving me so many errors as I have used swift 1.2

Comment: your problem is resolved bro..

Comment: no.. I am updating my Xcode.. @Anbu.Karthik

Comment: ya ok after that u get the same error reply here we will move on next step

Comment: ok.. But I want to say you that I have Xcode 7 and Xcode 6.4 both in my Mac. Till now When iOS 9.2 is installed in my device i was running my application successfully with Xcode 9.2. But with iOS 9.3 why not?@Anbu.Karthik

Comment: check your maximum deployment target on your xcode , it will support on particalualr level,

Comment: in Xcode 6.4 it is iOS 8.4

Comment: I updated Xcode 7.3 and running my application with Xcode 6.4... It works!!

Answer (score 1):

> You need to upgrade to the latest XCode.

Follow this link to upgrade your XCode. https://developer.apple.com/xcode/download/

Answer (score 1):

**Update your Xcode to the latest version .**

This error comes because of iOS version is incompatible with your Xcode version .

https://developer.apple.com/xcode/download/

**This link will help you to convert your project from Swift 1.2 to Swift 2.0**

[How to migrate my swift 1.2 project into 2.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31603557/how-to-migrate-my-swift-1-2-project-into-2-0)

Comment: I know that, but I have created my whole project with swift 1.2. and it is giving me so many errors if I am going to do so. as syntax are different.

Comment: Its true , but you can`t run your app on your device until Xcode gets updated .

Comment: Updated my answer . Please have  a look